# Change data type of all columns in a table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

If I want to transform the data type of all columns in a table (the number and the name of the columns can change in the future).
I found the following solution:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="YourTable"]}[Content],
    LSTHeaders = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
    HowMany = List.Count(LSTHeaders),
    Transformation = Table.TransformColumnTypes( Source, Table.ToRows(Table.FromColumns({LSTHeaders, List.Repeat({type number}, HowMany  )})))
in
    Transformation
```

It works fine but I don't know how to apply "en-US" data format.
I tried the following but didn't work:

```
Transformation = Table.TransformColumnTypes( Source, Table.ToRows(Table.FromColumns({LSTHeaders, List.Repeat({type number}, "en-US"}, HowMany  )})))
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the culture as the last argument in the `Table.TransformColumnTypes` function.

I usually do it like this:

```
   typeAll = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type number}),"en-US")
```

but you could modify yours:

```
Transformation = Table.TransformColumnTypes( Source, Table.ToRows(Table.FromColumns({LSTHeaders, List.Repeat({type number}, HowMany  )})),"en-US"),
```